# Android Wear How to dynamically switch Android Watch Face by code like 'Beautiful Watches' app does?

Tags: android-intent, wear-os

I am almost new to develop Android Wear app, and I start developing Android Wear app that allows users to switch the watch's face from their mobile (by clicking buttons, just like [Beautiful Watches app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.watchFrenzy)).

I have made an simple app that allows users to switch their wear's app's activity, but not the watch face itself.
I know that it is possible since Beautiful Watches app is doing what exactly what I want to do.

Is there any sample or code available? How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the official custom watch faces API launch, we have included configuration activities for companion apps on the phone. For more details, please check out:

#### Providing Configuration Activities

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/configuration.html

#### Android Wear Watch Face Samples

Located under the Android SDK directory:
`<sdk-directory>/samples/android-21/wearable/WatchFace`